# Print quality ruined after firmware update i3 mk3

Tags: prusa-i3, prusaslicer

I'll try to give as much detail as I know here but let me know if there is anything missing.

I have a Prusa i3 MK3 that I got in about 2018 and it was working perfectly fine. Print quality was pretty good. Then sometime in the last 6 months I updated slicer and the printer would give me an error about the file being for a different printer type. I ignored it because I was pretty sure I had it set right and the prints were still coming out fine. Then recently I updated to the latest firmware version (3.9.0) from the website for MK3. When I did the update it told me this was firmware for a different printer type but I ignored it because I had checked again that it was the right version. Now when I print I do not get a message about the printer being the wrong type but the prints fail every single time.

Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]

I have tried messing with the settings a bit but they used to work perfect on default. What should I do here? Revert to an older firmware version?

Comment: Firmware controls Z offset and steps per mm which impact on print quality, your prints looks like they are over extruding. As if you have the incorrect firmware for the hardware you have. You could revert to find out.